# Running Tasks from List

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-client-side

I am trying to run a task List using the following method:

```cs
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

tasks.Add(new Task(() => this.firstMethod()));
tasks.Add(new Task(() => this.secondMethod()));
```

However, if I use one of the two examples below I get the following issues:

```cs
foreach (Task task in tasks)
{
    await Task.Run(() => task);
}
```

In this first case, the tasks don't run at all.

```cs
foreach (Task task in tasks)
{
    task.Start();
    task.Wait();
}
```

In this second case, it runs only once, then I get the following error:

> Start may not be called on a task that has completed

What am I missing?

Comment: Why not just `await task;`?

Comment: `Task.WaitAll` or `Task.WhenAll`?

Comment: It's not clear how and why you want to use this, so not really answerable. Tasks are not threads and you have to interface this with the calling code somehow.

Comment: @maccettura tried that too, didn't work

Comment: @DragandDrop done that, didn´t work

Comment: Did you try my solution below? It's a passing unit test that shows how it works.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I want to save multiple premade tasks in an Array or List and run them whenever I need. I thought it was pretty clear

Comment: Tasks are one-shot only. And you dodn't specify if you want to run them in parallel or sequentially. But I'll post an answer.

Comment: `I want to save multiple premade tasks in an Array or List and run them whenever I need. I thought it was pretty clear` well it is unclear and unusual way to reuse task instance and run the same task from time to time. It is not supposed by .Net framework authors as you can see from `Start may not be called on a task that has completed`error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot re-use a Task. So let's start with creating an array of delegates

```
List<Action> tasks = new List<Action>();

tasks.Add(this.firstMethod);
tasks.Add(this.secondMethod);
```

and then run them sequentially, on additional threads (leaving the main thread free to update the UI):

```
foreach (Action task in tasks)
{
    await Task.Run(task);
}
```

but this loop could be done in many ways, depending on the context of the calling code and the nature of the payloads.

This may be not the best solution.

Comment: When I try to add the Tasks to the Action List I get this error "Cannot convert from Task to Action"

Comment: @JoãoPedroSousa, you need to understand the difference between an `Action` and a `Task`. A `Task` instance represents an asynchronous operation that performs the `Action`. You can create as many `Task` instances as you like from a single `Action`. But you can't assign a `Task` instance to an `Action` variable.

Comment: I proposed an edit to Henk's answer, renaming `task` and `tasks` to `action` and `actions`, respectively. This should highlight the distinction between tasks and actions, which are not the same.

Comment: When the signature is `void firstMethod() {...}` then you should take the text from this answer literally. It should work.

Comment: @ThomasBarnekow - I have rejected that edit, in this case task is a domain related name.

Comment: Ok, I got the solution. It's exactelly what you have except for the part where you add the Actions to the list which was missing the lambda expression "tasks.Add(() => this.firstMethod())". Thank you very much for your help and explanation on how Actions and Tasks work

Comment: @HenkHolterman, in my eyes, the name `task` is misleading in this case and confused the OP.

Comment: @JoãoPedroSousa - you shouldn't need the lambda expression. Post a sample of firstMethod() to clear this up. It does return `void`, yes?

Comment: The small details do matter, as you tagged this `[client-side]`. You only have 1 thread in Wasm, use it wisely.

Comment: Yes it returns void but it won't work without the lambda expression. I don't know if it should work or not but the truth is that it doesn't

Answer (score 2):

Here's a unit test that shows how you can do this:

```cs
    public class TasksTests
    {
        private readonly ITestOutputHelper _output;

        public TasksTests(ITestOutputHelper output)
        {
            _output = output ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(output));
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task CanCreateAndRunTasks()
        {
            var tasks = new List<Task>
            {
                new Task(() => _output.WriteLine("Task #1")),
                new Task(() => _output.WriteLine("Task #2"))
            };

            tasks.ForEach(t => t.Start());

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }
    }
```

You first create the tasks. Then you need to start them. Lastly, you need to await them all, e.g., using `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: When I run the "tasks.ForEach" command the second time I get "Start may not be called on a task that has completed"

Comment: Just to be sure, are **you** calling `tasks.ForEach(t => t.Start())` twice? You can't do that obviously, because the tasks will have been started after the first time. Mind you a `Task` instance represents an asynchronous operation. Once that operation has been started or even already completed, you can't start it again. You will have to create a new `Task`.

Comment: Yes, that is written in the description. How can I call it more that once then? If I call it directly (await this.firstMethod()) I can do it as many times as I want, however, If I add it to the List ot only runs once.

Comment: @JoãoPedroSousa, you did not state your intention to run those "tasks" (or actions) multiple times. Had you made that clear in your question, my answer would have been different.

Comment: In the explanation I said "In this second case, it runs only once, then I get the following error" which means I get that error when I run it the second time. Looks clear as water to me

Comment: @JoãoPedroSousa, just to provide feedback, this did **not** clearly state your intention, which you could see from the answers. Only after you stated that wanted to run those actions multiple times, which you would not do with `Task` instances, did Henk provide an answer that dealt with that intent.

Comment: On a final note. If I say that it only runs the first time and then I get an error, it is implied that I tried to run it more than once. I am sorry that you didn't understand it but I DID state my intention, despite the fact that you didn't get it.

Answer (score 0):

the first case sample

```cs
foreach (Task task in tasks)
{
    await Task.Run(() => task);
}
```

should be changed to

```cs
foreach (Task task in tasks)
{
    task.Start(); // there is no sense to await since tasks should be run in parallel I suppose
}
```

The second case is not clear however.
Do you run the second case after the first one ? It should be fine if you have `tasks` just initialized before the `Start` call, like

```cs
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>()
{
new Task(() => this.firstMethod()),
new Task(() => this.secondMethod()),
};
foreach (Task task in tasks)
{
    task.Start();
    task.Wait(); // this causes tasks to be run in sequence (one by one) like with await in the first sample
}
```

the most simplest case is to use [Task.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.8)

```cs
var tasks = new[Task]
{
Task.Run(firstMethod),
Task.Run(secondMethod),
}; // tasks are started immediately there is no need to start them later

Task.WaitAll(tasks); // wait until all tasks are finished
```

Comment: In this case It will run the task the first time instead of only adding it to the array, am I right? I don't want that to happen, I want to add the tasks to an array or list without running them immediately